# Running bash-commands with keeping directory-changes

Tags: python, bash, command-line

You can chain commands to allow directory-changes:

```
from os import system

system(
    "cd ./assets/" "; "
    "bash loadData.sh" ";"
    # here should come tasks in the python-source
    "ls -al >> ./../directory" "; "
)
```

But how can you execute the second command, after some calculations in python are done?/How do you store the bash-context and reuse it later?

**Edit:**

The output can be displayed to stdout or to a pipe-object from subprocess, but the directory-changes and **assignments of variables** in the bash-code should be kept in any form (I want to execute real bash-commands to change directory and do not want to use `os.chdir`)

Comment: Google the `subprocess` module, you can save the output from bash, etc.

Comment: I think what you want to do is not so clear. You may need to improve your question.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you exactly want to do, but you can even do very complex variable assignments with subprocess as follows:

```
import subprocess as sp

p = sp.Popen("cd assets; var=$(bash loadData.sh); var2=$(python -c \"print '${var}123'\"); echo ${var2}", stdout=sp.PIPE, shell=True)
output = p.stdout.read()
print output
```

Comment: The output is piped but the main problem stays, you cannot keep variable-assignments with just piping the program.